# Haxe Type Not Found FileSystem

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to compile FNF but it's just giving me this error:
source/Paths.hx:242: characters 7-17 : Type not found : FileSystem

Can someone help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FileSystem not supported for html5 build.
Solutions:

1. You can build fnf for sys target (windows or other).
2. You can use conditional compilation to remove FileSystem from html5 build.

Example:

```
#if sys
trace(FileSystem.readDirectory(path));
#end
```